# How to validate comma separated option argument in Bash?

Tags: bash

How to validate possible combination of list of arguments?

My script look something like this, which validates if user pass parameter other than apple,banana or mango:

```
validate() {
    if [[ "$2" != "apple" ]] && [[ "$2" != "mango" ]] && [[ "$2" != "banana" ]]; then
        echo  "--fruits should always be \"apple\", \"mango\", \"banana\""
    fi
    
}

args_() {
    if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "please enter valid parameter"
    fi

    for ARGUMENT in "$@"; do
        KEY=$(echo $ARGUMENT | cut -f1 -d=)
        VALUE=$(echo $ARGUMENT | cut -f2 -d=)

        case "$KEY" in
        --fruits)
            validate ${KEY} ${VALUE}
            ;;
        *) ;;
        esac

    done
}

args_ $*
```

But I want to pass the validation if users pass parameters in combination also.
e.g.

`bash validate.sh --fuits=apple,mango`

OR

`bash validate.sh --fruits=apple,banana,mango`

Is there a way to verify possible list of arguments in bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should validate each component of the value separately.

```
fruits=$2,
while test "$fruits"; do
  case ${fruits%%,*} in
  (apple|banana|mango) ;;
  (*)
    # handle error here
  esac
  fruits=${fruits#*,}
done
```

Comment: Can you explain ` fruits=${fruits#*,}` this?

Comment: And can't I store `(apple|banana|mango)` in variable?

Comment: @L Given `fruits=apple,banana`, `fruits=${fruits#*,}` removes `apple,` from the value of `fruits` and assigns the result back. And no, you can't. If you have to, you should use another loop that compares `${fruits%%,*}` with each whitelisted word instead of a `case` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert ',' into ' ' to make your arguements as an array and make a for loop inside that:

```sh
for FRUIT in $(echo $VALUE | tr ',' ' '); do
    validate ${KEY} ${FRUIT}
done
```

In your code:

```sh
args_() {
        ...
        case "$KEY" in
        --fruits)
            for FRUIT in $(echo $VALUE | tr "," " "); do
                validate ${KEY} ${FRUIT}
            done
            ;;  
        *) ;;
        esac
        ...
```

Test:

```sh
$ bash main.sh --fruits=apple                        # Accepted
$ bash main.sh --fruits=apple,mangodd                # Not Accepted - Typo
--fruits should always be "apple", "mango", "banana"
$ bash main.sh --fruits=apple,banana                 # Accepted
```

Also here is my version of your code:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# List of your fruits
FRUIT_LIST=(apple banana mango)

# Validate Function
validate() {
    ACCEPTED_MSG="$2 is Accepted."
    NOT_ACCEPTED_MSG="$2 is wrong, check $ $0 --help"
    (for e in "${FRUIT_LIST[@]}"; do [[ "$e" == "$2" ]] && exit 0; done) && echo $ACCEPTED_MSG || echo $NOT_ACCEPTED_MSG
}

# Return Help
usage() {
    cat <<EOF
usage: $0 [OPTIONS]

Options:
    --fruits=[fruit]        Validate your fruit(s)    

Example:
    $0 --fruits=banana,mango
EOF
}

# Main Functionality
main() {
    [ $# -eq 0 ] && echo "please enter valid parameter"

    for ARGUMENT in "$@"; do
        KEY=$(echo $ARGUMENT | cut -f1 -d=)
        VALUE=$(echo $ARGUMENT | cut -f2 -d=)
        case "$KEY" in
        --fruits)
            for FRUIT in $(echo $VALUE | tr "," " "); do
                validate ${KEY} ${FRUIT}
            done
        ;;
        *)
            usage
        ;;
        esac

    done
}

# Run Main
main $*
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, the problem with your code is if I pass `--fruits=app` then also the validation passes

Comment: @LLawliet Yes, you are right, I fixed the issue on line 10 on my version of the code, it should work correct now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like so. Here we also ensure that at least one of the options is present.

```
validate() {
    local regex='(apple|mango|banana)'
    regex+="^$regex(,$regex)*\$"
    if ! [[ "$2" =~ $regex ]]; then
        echo '--fruits must be a list of "apple", "mango", "banana"'
        return 1
    fi   
}
```

By the way: To split `--fruits=...` into `--fruits` and `...` you can use bash's parameter expansion. This is not only safer than `VALUE=$(echo $ARGUMENT | cut -f2 -d=)` but also faster. Also, the recommended style for variable names is lowercase, to avoid accidental collisions with special variables and environment variables.

```
key=${argument%%=*}
value=${argument#*=}
```